# Nested for loop resets iterator even though the iterator is manipulated

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

my code is something like this:

```
something = True

for i in range(5):
    if something: 
        for ii in range (2):
            print(i)
            i += 1
        something = False

    print(i)
```

The output is:

```
0
1
2
1
2
3
4
```

But what I expect is 0 to 4 because the i is manipulated in the ii-loop. What's wrong in my code?

Comment: The loop variable is reassigned by the for loop at each iteration. If you want to skip iterations, use a while loop.

Comment: You can also use `continue` but you may just want to do a `while`.